# using php password_hash passwords with freeradius

Tags: php, authentication, freeradius

I have a database with usernames and passwords that are encrypted using password_hash that are used for several other applications.

I would like to reuse these passwords for authenticating the users using freeradius (for wifi access).

I'm using  FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.15, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Jul 28 2017 at 06:41:27 FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.15 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. The clients are Unifi AP PRO.

I start from a default installation with minimal changes to the config. For testing purposes, I added one user with clear text username and password in users. That user works.

In sites-enabled/default I added in the authorize section

```
update control {Auth-type := "/usr/bin/php -f /etc/freeradius/php/checkpasswd.php'%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}'"}
```

at the very beginning of the authorize section.
The relevant part of checkpasswd.php is

```
//arguments ophalen
$username_radius = $argv[1];
$password_radius = $argv[2];

//wachtwoorden opzoeken in de databank
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT passwordHash FROM gebruikers WHERE username = :username');
$query->bindParam(':username', $username_radius);
$query->execute();
$row_count = $query->rowCount();
if ($row_count != 1){
    echo 'Reject';
    }
    else {

//is de hash van het radiuswachtwoord gelijk aan de hash in de databank?
        $rs = $query->fetchAll();
        $passwordHash = $rs[0][0];
        if (password_verify($password_radius,$passwordHash)) {
            echo 'Accept';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Reject';
        }
```

(sorry for the Dutch comments)
Basically it says Accept when password matches and Reject in all other cases.

I understood that I need to use TTLS / PAP to be able to see the password. But the password never ends up on my server. I get the following output with freeradius -X

```
(0) Received Access-Request Id 18 from 10.1.8.99:55827 to 192.168.2.32:1812 length 157
(0)   User-Name = "krog"
(0)   NAS-Identifier = "24a43cb081ea"
(0)   NAS-Port = 0
(0)   Called-Station-Id = "36-A4-3C-B1-81-EA:ritaexam"
(0)   Calling-Station-Id = "48-45-20-FB-4B-31"
(0)   Framed-MTU = 1400
(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
(0)   Connect-Info = "CONNECT 0Mbps 802.11b"
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x02660009016b726f67
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0xfa1433a62a8b77ea794a62ac47f8320d
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     update control {
(0)       EXPAND /usr/bin/php -f /etc/freeradius/php/checkpasswd.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}'
(0)          --> /usr/bin/php -f /etc/freeradius/php/checkpasswd.php 'krog' ''
(0)     } # update control = fail
(0)   } # authorize = fail
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
(0)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(0) attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(0) attr_filter.access_reject:    --> krog
(0) attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(0)     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(0) eap: Request was previously rejected, inserting EAP-Failure
(0) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 102 length 4
(0)     [eap] = updated
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(0) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Waking up in 0.6 seconds.
(0) Sending delayed response
(0) Sent Access-Reject Id 18 from 192.168.2.32:1812 to 10.1.8.99:55827 length 44
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x04660004
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

As you can see, the User-Password is nowhere in the communication. I found various posts that mention that this should work. Am I missing the obvious somewhere?

Thank you for your insights.
Koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

```
update control {Auth-type := "/usr/bin/php -f /etc/freeradius/php/checkpasswd.php'%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}'"}
```

to

```
update control {Auth-type := `/usr/bin/php -f /etc/freeradius/php/checkpasswd.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}'`}
```

fixed the error for me
(using ` instead of ")

Comment: Finally managed to go on with this project and I can confirm that your solution works! Thanks a lot.